# What is an alternative to insertSublayer in swiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, swiftui

I am creating a cameraApp as part of a project I am doing and I am relatively new to swiftUI. I am using `AVFoundation` and I need to create a previewLayer. However, I am unable to create a `previewLayer` because I don't know how I can display it. I have followed a few tutorials and read Apple's documentation.

This is what my code looks like

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?


    func setupCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.canSetSessionPreset(.high)
    }

    mutating func setupDevice() {
        let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera,
        for: .video, position: .unspecified)

        currentCamera = videoDevice
    }

    func setupInputOutput() {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput!.supportedPhotoCodecTypes(for: .jpg)
        } catch {
            print("err")
        }
    }

    mutating func setupPreviewLayer() {
        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = 
        AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
    }

    func startRunningCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }    


    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out?